# How to test for a device at an I2C address

Tags: gpio, i2c, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I use `i2c-detect` to find connected i2c devices on my Raspberry. For example:

[image]

Now I want to use that information to perform some tasks, for example:

```
if “Address 76 is connected”:

DO STUFF
```

For this, I need a numeric output from i2c-detect, like "76", as in the output table shown above. How should I proceed?

Comment: I do not understand the question.  If English is not your first language try Google Translate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you could write your own program ... examine the source code of i2c-detect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to test a known address with `i2cget`:

```bash
if i2cget -y 1 0x76
then
    echo "device 0x76 is there"
else
    echo "device 0x76 is missing"
fi
```

Note that there is no universal detection method on I2C. `i2cdetect` uses different methods for different addresses, unless you tell it which method to use. `i2cget` is the equivalent of `i2cdetect -r`. This may confuse write-only chips.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `i2c-tools` package, you should start by reading the available documentation. Two items I'd recommend are:

1. The [summary & system manuals for `i2c-tools`](https://www.mankier.com/package/i2c-tools) provides a useful overview, and has links to the I2C Wiki, and the `git` source tree.
2. The 4-part I2C programming tutorial from AB Electronics(https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1090/i2c-part-1---introducing-i2c)

After you finish this, you may have a different view toward the toolset to use (e.g. Python's [`smbus2` library](https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/)) in your project, or you may decide that the `i2c-tools` package is a good fit. In any case, some familiarity with the options will be a benefit.

Wrt using the `i2c-tools` package for your development, I think that there are options available (e.g. the [MATLAB version](https://github.com/MLAB-project/i2c-tools)) that you may wish to consider. Also, perhaps consider your approach in light of your programming experience; for example, extracting the device address you need from the `i2c-detect` output will demand some additional programming to parse the output; do you have any experience parsing text with `sed` or `awk`?

So - that's one way to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Python which tests for devices on Pi I2C buses 0 and 1.  It needs the pigpio daemon to be running (`sudo pigpiod`).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pigpio

pigpio.exceptions = False # handle errors

pi = pigpio.pi()

for bus in range(2):
   for x in range(0x08, 0x79):
      h = pi.i2c_open(bus, x)
      if h >= 0:
         s = pi.i2c_read_byte(h)
         if s >= 0:
            print("device {} found on bus {}".format(x, bus))
         pi.i2c_close(h)

pi.stop()
```

Look at the `i2cdetect` documentation (`man i2cdetect`) for why this sort of test can be risky.